# How to force a straight line in Draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I am drawing this:

[image]

And, I simply cannot make the line straight as all lines should be!
No matter what I move, the line still has that break. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

You can select the resistor (the 'sawtooth') by clicking it, and move it to the right with the right arrow button on your keyboard. This enables you to move it pixel-by-pixel instead of being constrained by the grid lines:

[image]

Alternatively (if the objects need to stay where they are but the line needs to be straight) you can adjust the line style in the sidebar widget:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work with the figure I am using ("npn"). I think the dot where the connection should come from in this figure is fundamentally displaced. So anything I connect it to ends up in non-straight lines. I mean, the emitter terminal of npn figure is not lined up with grid lines, the entire figure is though but it does not help.